# ¿Cómo llenar un combo con horas y minutos cada cierto intervalo de tiempo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo que mostrar en un combo las horas y minutos que me traigo del DB, los datos que tengo son:

- hora_inicio: 08
- minuto_:inicio: 00
- hora_fin: 13
- minuto_fin: 00
- intervalo: 10 (también me traigo el intervalo del DB)

Tengo que armar el combo (usando jQuery) y meter ahí en un `foreach` supongo que en las horas, o sea que me permita seleccionar:

- 08:00
- 08:10
- 08:20
- 08:30

Hasta llegar a la hora final que son las `13:00` en este caso. Todos estos datos los traigo de la base de datos, los intervalos son dinámicos. Las horas y los minutos también dependen de un cronograma, porque es un sistema de turnos, a veces es cada 10 minutos y otras veces un turno cada 5 minutos, etc.

No tengo idea de por donde empezar tengo 4 meses programando y me dejaron este proyecto para resolver, desde ya muchas gracias!

```
if(response.success) {
    var hora_inicio = (response.data[0].hora_inicio).split(':');
    var hora_fin = (response.data[0].hora_fin).split(':');
    var intervalo = response.data[0].intervalo;

    //hora_inicio = hora_inicio[0] + ':' + hora_inicio[1]; // en posiocion 0 trae la hora 08 y en pos 1 trae min 00
    //hora_fin = hora_fin[0] + ':' + hora_fin[1];
        
    // crear un array con todas las horas disponibles, desde las 08:00 + intervalo hasta llegar a 13:00  
    hora_inicio = parseInt(hora_inicio[0]);
    minuto_inicio = parseInt(hora_inicio[1]);
    hora_final = parseInt(hora_fin[0]);
    minuto_final = parseInt(hora_fin[1]);

    horasCombo.append('<option value="'+ id_dias +'">'+ hora_inicio +'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Me surgen 2 dudas con respecto al problema que planteas:

1. ¿El intervalo es contante para el horario a crear?, quiero decir, si el horario que vas a crear tiene intervalos salteados o si va a ser un intervalo fijo para todo ese horario en especifico.
2. ¿La hora de entrada y la hora de salida son congruentes con el intervalo que tomas?, Por ejemplo, en el caso que planteas empiezas a las 8:00 y terminas a las 13:10, con un intervalo de 10 min, la hora final es exacta, pero por en cambio si si tomamos las mismas horas que propones pero con un intervalo de 3 min la hora final seria de 13:09 no de 13:10.

Pregunte lo anterior ya que el código que hice no cubre esos 2 casos, pero para un escenario en el que planteas te debería de dar el horario de un día completo.

```
let getTime = (hour, minute, step) => {
    nextMinute = minute + step > 59 ? 60 - (minute + step) : minute + step;
    nextHour = nextMinute > minute ? hour : hour + 1 > 23 ? 0 : hour + 1;
        return [nextHour, nextMinute];
};

let padTime = (time) => `${`${time[0]}`.padStart(2, '0')}:${`${time[1]}`.padEnd(2, '0')}`;

let makeSchedule = (currentTime, endTime, step) => {
    let nextTime = getTime(currentTime[0], currentTime[1], step);
    return nextTime.join(':') !== endTime.join(':')?
        `${padTime(currentTime)}-${makeSchedule(nextTime, endTime, step)}`
        : `${padTime(currentTime)}-${padTime(nextTime)}`;
};

const startTime = [8, 0];
const endTime = [13, 10];
const interval = 10;
const scheduleList = makeSchedule(startTime, endTime, interval).split('-');
```

Lo que se hace es el siguiente:

1. Declaro una función **getTime** que toma una hora, un minuto y un intervalo en en base al intervalo calculo que ambos estén un rango "normal", osea que la suma del intervalo no de mas de 59 ni las horas mas de 23 y de ser así represarlos a 0 según corresponda.
2. La función **padTime** toma un array de 2 valores (la hora y los minutos) y los pasa a string agregando los correspondientes 0 para darle buena presentación.
3. **makeSchedule** es una función recursiva, toma tu hora actual, tu hora final y el intervalo, mientras la suma de la hora actual con el intervalo sea diferente se continuara llamando a si misma, al final regresa un string con todas las horas del horario unidas con el carácter '-'.
4. Después de todo lo anterior tomo el string resultante de la función **makeSchedule**, separo las horas basado en el carácter '-' y las guardo en un arreglo.

Ya para terminal, aquí te dejo un ejemplo final del script anterior ya en una pagina HTMl que muestra el horrario en un **select** con sus correspondientes **options**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="">
            <label for="schedul">Chose you schedule</label>
            <select name="schedule" id="schedule"></select>
            <script>
                let getTime = (hour, minute, step) => {
                    nextMinute = minute + step > 59 ? 60 - (minute + step) : minute + step;
                    nextHour = nextMinute > minute ? hour : hour + 1 > 23 ? 0 : hour + 1;
                    return [nextHour, nextMinute];
                };

                let padTime = (time) => `${`${time[0]}`.padStart(2, '0')}:${`${time[1]}`.padEnd(2, '0')}`;

                let makeSchedule = (currentTime, endTime, step) => {
                    let nextTime = getTime(currentTime[0], currentTime[1], step);
                    return nextTime.join(':') !== endTime.join(':')
                        ? `${padTime(currentTime)}-${makeSchedule(nextTime, endTime, step)}`
                        : `${padTime(currentTime)}-${padTime(nextTime)}`;
                };

                const scheduleList = makeSchedule([8, 0], [13, 10], 10).split('-');

                const selectTag = document.querySelector('#schedule');
                scheduleList.forEach( time => {
                    const option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.innerText = time;
                    selectTag.appendChild(option);
                });
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Toma muy en cuenta los primeros puntos que plantee al incio de la respuesta, si tus respuestas a las preguntas que te plantee fueron:

1. El intervalo es fijo.
2. Las horas son congruentes con el intervalo.

No deberías tener problema con el script y debería de andar bien, si tus respuestas fueron diferentes, es probable que caigas en un bucle infinito. Total hay mejores soluciones pero esta es la que se me ocurre de a rápido, ojala te sirva.

Comment: Si exacto los intervalo cambian, pero me sirvio para lo que necesito gracias!